# How to add maven dependencies to an Eclipse Plugin Project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I try to add Maven dependency for my plugin project, but it doesn't work.
Always get NoClassDefFoundError. Somebody can explain me what should I do?

Comment: Everything an Eclipse plugin uses must be either in the current plugin or in some other plugin and listed in the MANIFEST.MF Require-Bunde or Import-Package.

Comment: This means there is no way to use thirdparty library via Maven?

Comment: The Eclipse plugin system that runs your plugin knows nothing about maven. You may be able to use maven + tycho to build the plugin (not sure, I don't use this) but the final resulting plugin must be as I said.